# How can can I combine two IF statement in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How can I combine two IF statement in Excel?

The first IF is checking a start date (in the MMDDYY format) from one cell (`Staff!$G5`) and if that date is greater than or equal to a date (in the MMDDYY format) in a cell on my active sheet (`S1`), I want it to execute a formula `(Staff!$D5*SetupTab!$B$3))*S$2)`.

So this formula works for me to perform this function:
`=IF(S$1>=Staff!$G5,Staff!$D5*SetupTab!$B$3))*S$2`

The caveat is that if an end date (cell `Staff!$H5`) is past the date in the same S1 cell, rather than execute the formula, the cell value would just be zero.

So it would need to be something along this line, but this doesn't appear to be properly checking both of these IF values:
`=IF(S$1>=Staff!$G5, IF(S$1>=Staff!$H5 Staff!$D5*SetupTab!$B$3))*S$2`

A little background/clarification on what I am trying to accomplish...this is a finance type report that will calculate expense per month for an employee.  The main formula calculates the expense for me, but if an employee leaves the company, I no longer need to forecast that expense past their end date, which is why I want it to "zero out".  Likewise, if I have a new employee starting in two months, but I want to get them on the books now to start to forecast them, I don't want their expense to start to calculate until their actual start date.

Update: The basic idea of the formula is to determine if I need to forecast expense for an employee for a given month. There are two totally separate variables, so it is not a matter of variable1 and variable2...the two IF statements are independent of one another.

1) If they are an active employee in a month...with their start date in cell "staff!G5" being prior or equal to the current month (cell S1), and there is no end date (cell staff!H5),then I would want dollars forecasted.

2) If they haven't yet started (eg, their start date in cell "staff!H5" is for a month or two down the road), then the forecast would be zero dollars until the month of their start.

3) If there is an end date in cell "staff!H5", then my forecast should be zero for all months after the end date

I really hope this is making some small amount of sense to someone out there :)
I have attached a screen shot compilation to hopefully help explain.

[image: IF Statement Annotated Screen Shots]

Comment: You're missing the TRUE and FALSE conditions from both of those IF statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Formula is saying that the payment date should be greater than the end date you should reverse the sign like the following:
`=IF(And(S$1>=Staff!$G5,or(S$1 <= Staff!H5,isblank(Staff!H5))),Staff!$D5 * Setup!$B$3 * S$2,0)`
Now this formula takes in consideration empty end date(that is the reason for all 0)

Comment: Thank you for the input.  I just pasted in your updated formula, and unfortunately it resulted in my values all being zeros.  I am going to make a few more updates to my original question to try to provide additional details.

Comment: I think the formula should test if the end date is empty and give result

Comment: I have corrected the formula to calculate result when the end date is empty

Comment: By George, I think you got it!  I had to add a couple "$" to keep the formula pulling the correct values from the staff tab, but this final formula seems to be working perfectly!
=IF(AND(S$1>=Staff!$G5,OR(S$1 <= Staff!$H5,ISBLANK(Staff!$H5))),Staff!$D5 * Setup!$B$3 * S$2,0)

Answer (score 0):

use `AND()` to check both conditions:

```
=IF(AND(S$1>=OtherTab!$G6, S$1>=OtherTab!$H6), OtherTab!$D6*SetupTab!$B$3, 0)
```

i,e

```
=IF(AND(condition1, condition2), value_if_both_true, else_value)
```

Comment: Thanks!  A formula guru, I am not!

I had to edit the formula tiny bit, as it was missing one of the values
=IF(AND(S$1>=OtherTab!$G5,S$1>=OtherTab!$H5), OtherTab!$D5*SetupTab!$B$3*S$2,0)

But the formula seems to be ignoring the IF statements, as it returns the same result, whether or not there are dates in the "Start" (OtherTab!G5) or "End" (OtherTab!H5) cells...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the formula is ignoring the if statements". can you post some screenshots?

Comment: I'm not sure if a screen shot will help, bottom line, if there is an end date (in cell OtherTab!H5) then the value returned in the target cell should be zero, whereas the formula is reporting the full value (as if there was no date in the end date), which is what I mean by the formula ignoring the values. The same thing is happening with the first statement regarding the start date...the purpose of the formula should also be if there is no start date listed in cell OtherTab!$G5, then the formula result should be zero, but again the value reported is a full month expense.

Comment: Describe in plain words what the input, processing logic and output is. Edit your question to do that. Don't post that in a comment. Describe the data types of each input, i.e. text, number, date.  Posting a screenshot ***would*** actually help see what you see.

Comment: I am hoping that the annotated screen shot(s) that I added to my original post will better clarify what I am attempting to do...

Comment: @WestsideBill: your sample in the first comment says "if date is greater than/equal to start date AND greater than/equal to end date". This compound statement will only be true if both sub parts evaluate as true.

Comment: That is an error on my part then...these should be two separate variables...I need to check the start date and see if I need to allocate $, but I also separately need to check the end date to zero out dollars if they no longer work with us.  This is what gets me back to trying how to combine these two separate IF statements into one formula.

Answer (score 0):

1) If they are an active employee in a month...with their start date in cell "staff!G5" being prior or equal to the current month (cell S1), and there is no end date (cell staff!H5),then I would want dollars forecasted.

```
AND(s$1 <= Staff!G5, Staff!H5 = 0)
```

2) If they haven't yet started (eg, their start date in cell "staff!H5" is for a month or two down the road), then the forecast would be zero dollars until the month of their start.

```
(s$1 > Staff!G5)
```

3) If there is an end date in cell "staff!H5", then my forecast should be zero for all months after the end date

```
(s$1 > Staff!H5)
```

So your logic should be "if (case2 OR case3) THEN 0 OTHERWISE if case1 THEN calculate OTHERWISE 0

```
=IF(
OR((s$1 > Staff!G5),(s$1 > Staff!H5))
,0,
(
IF(
AND(s$1 <= Staff!G5, Staff!H5 = 0)
,
(Staff!$D5 * Setup!$B$3 * S$2)
,0
))
)
```

(not tested, and I broke it up a little for readability)

Comment: This version also reports back all values as zero.
One thing that I may be throwing you off on...the two key variables are actually separate variables (rather than variable 1 AND variable 2)
...I need to check the start date and see if I need to allocate $, but I also separately need to check the end date to zero out dollars if they no longer work with us. This is what gets me back to trying how to combine these two separate IF statements into one formula